# How do I get a permalink to my search results?

Tags: feature-request, search, permalink

Is there a way to get a permanent link to the current search results?

Suppose one fine day I am going through questions (to answer) posted that day. I answered a few questions but now it's getting late and the clock reads 23:00 but there are still many questions remaining which I haven't looked into so I want to save this search to resume it tomorrow.But if I bookmark the URL it won't  work because even though it has filters it has no absolute time references so bookmarks like [*stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?page=10&sort=newest&pagesize=50*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?page=13&sort=newest&pagesize=50) would only show the latest 50 questions that fall on 10th page which would be useless in such scenarios because page no. will keep on changing when new questions are posted so only alternative is hit and trial to get to the page you were on

Is there some easy way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to limit results to a date range. The query [`[javascript] is:q created:...2017-01-16`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&pagesize=50&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a...2017-01-16) lists all questions asked *up until today*; this will be more or less stable (only deleted posts will disappear from it, shifting things slightly).

I'd not bother however, as you'll never answer them all. Stack Overflow averages [42 new Javascript questions per hour](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/616420/javascript-questions-per-hour). A good night sleep will add 340 new questions to the list, which should keep you busy the rest of the day, by which time another 680 new questions will have been added. Can you keep up with that?

Comment: There are date relative shortcuts, like 1d, 1w, 1y, etc...

Comment: @Braiam: sure, but if the OP wanted a stable list, using relative shortcuts would not give them that. They may as well stick to their current approach then.

Comment: I meant as helper of getting the date right, since the options appear in the side bar.

Comment: Well, the good part is, of those 42 JavaScript questions per hour, 24 are duplicates... Of course, those will also be answered, but I digress...

Comment: @Braiam: Look at the URL, it still is a search for a relative date. Tomorrow, the same search URL will start from a different date, relative to the shifted 'today'.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: the OP has not filtered those out at any rate. They are now looking at page 10, each 50 questions, so they looked at less than 500 questions. That's the output of just 12 hours. I'm assuming they ignored the duplicates that did get closed in that. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right no1 can answer all of them .But my point is most of the time you can easily decide whether you'll answer or not in just 10-15 secs of reading (ignoring rare cases when OP posts a story!) .So by ignoring questions with “tough tags” me it takes just  3-4 minutes to paginate over 50 posts all thanks to additional help from [duplicate] and downvotes that's why I wanted to save the state.Your method is very close to being helpful in this scenario

Comment: @Novice: perhaps you should start ignoring tags too then. And you can filter on questions with a score of 0 or higher too. Read the advanced search page carefully.